# Using Output Clause with CTE throws mult-part identifier could not be bound error

Tags: sql, sql-update, common-table-expression, output-clause

I am trying to use Output clause with update statement(using CTE). But I repeatedly receive multi-part identifier could not be bound error.

```
;With CTE_Duplicates as
(  SELECT
    t1.[Id] as ID1, t2.[Id] as ID2
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
      Id, Value,TypeID, DatabaseID
    FROM
       TypeValue
       where DatabaseID in (1)   
    ) T1
   JOIN
   (
    SELECT 
     Id,Value,TypeID, DatabaseID
    FROM
       TypeValue
       where DatabaseID in (2)   
    ) T2 on
    T1.Value = T2.Value AND T1.dTypeID = T2.TypeID and T2.DatabaseID in (1,2)
    )
update Scenario set Scenario .[Symbol] = CTE_Duplicates.[ID1]
    output  inserted.Symbol, deleted.Symbol, Scenario.ID
    into Log(newid,oldid, TableID)
    from  CTE_Duplicates INNER JOIN Scenario ON CTE_Duplicates.ID1=Scenario.Symbol
    where Scenario.[Symbol]= CTE_Duplicates.[ID2]
```

> Error: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
>
> The multi-part identifier "Scenario.ID" could not be bound.

Comment: You are only allowed to reference `inserted` and `deleted` in the `output` clause.

Comment: any idea how we can insert that particular column in this scenario? thanks in advance

Comment: . . You can't.  You have to join back to the data being inserted.